# Sleeping within nested for loops in bash

Tags: bash, loops, sleep

I have a pair of nested `for` loops in a `bash` shell script.

I want to pause the script every 60 seconds when a counter hits a multiple of 50 "ticks" or iterations, so I put in a modulo test:

```
counter=1
for ((i=0; i<${#libraries[@]}; i++)); do
    for ((j=(i+1); j<${#libraries[@]}; j++)); do
        # do stuff...
        if [ $counter%50 == 0 ]; then
            sleep 60s
        fi
        counter=$[$counter+1]
    done
done
```

This loop behaves erratically — specifically, this script does not pause every 50 iterations, but occasionally staggers and mostly skips or otherwise does not appear to be triggering the expected `sleep` call correctly.

Whatever I put into `# do stuff...` this script does not pause as expected, but behaves in roughly the same erratic way. I can comment it out — same behavior.

The `${#libraries[@]}` stuff is just an array of file paths.

Does `sleep` not work inside loops, or am I not using it correctly? Is there an alternative way to pause the script without breaking out the nested loops into separate wrapper scripts?

Comment: `$[...]` was deprecated *decades* ago; use `$((...))` instead.

Comment: Also the trailing `s` after `60` in your `sleep` command is suspicious, check your `man sleep`.  The program probably ignores it, but I doubt it should be there.

Comment: No, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test is wrong.  Try this instead :

```
if (( counter % 50 == 0 ))
```

The `$counter%50` part will never expand to `0`, so this test will always fail, and the sleep will never be executed.  The `%` modulo operator requires an arithmetic context, which the standard test command does not provide, but the double parentheses will.

Comment: Rest assured I am an idiot too, we all take turns :).